# Hello world example for circos?

Tags: circos

Can somebody provide me with a "hello world" example for circos? (www.circos.ca)

I know there are tons of tutorials provided with the zipped distribution, yet the way I learn is to take the very minimum config and then build from that - and I could not find that.

So, anyone to help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developer of circos answered my question on another forum:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/circos-data-visualization/FGWmZqNexoM

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Martin (circos's author) is very nice in circos's google group ( http://groups.google.com/group/circos-data-visualization ).

BTW, your problem is very simple :) Just follow this after you download and install circos :

```
cd your-circos-root-dir
bin/circos -conf example/circos.conf
```

Maybe you will meet some common errors like perl modules installation error when install circos, just follow here: http://circos.ca/documentation/tutorials/configuration/